# Show that $C^{Lip}$ is dense in $C^0(M, R)$

Tags: real-analysis

$C^{Lip}$ is the set of Lipschitz functions defined on a compact metric space $M$. $C^0(M, R)$ is the set of real-valued continuous function defined on a compact metric space $M$. I can easily show that $C^{Lip}$ is a function algebra on $M$, but I get stuck trying to show the other two assumptions of Stone-Weierstrass theorem, that it vanishes nowhere in $M$ and separates points in $M$. For the vanishing nowhere property, I tried using contradiction and assumed there is a $p \in M$ such that $f(p) = 0$ for all $f \in C^{Lip}$. Then I got stuck. Maybe I should do something with the Lipschitz condition? And for the separating points property, maybe I need to use the fact that $C^{Lip}$ is a function algebra? That's about everything I can think about. Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: constant functions are Lipschitz.

Hint 2: distance functions $d_a(x)= d(x,a)$ are Lipschitz (use the triangle inequality).

These give you the two missing assumptions of Stone-Weierstrass.

By the way, I never saw the notation $C^{Lip}(M)$ until now... $\operatorname{Lip}(M)$ and $C^{0,1}$ are both common, the second being a part of $C^{k,\alpha}$ Hölder spaces.

Comment: +1; This is one of my favorite tricks. Very useful when trying to play with shift spaces.